# How to get this deal card fuction working for a BlackJack game?

Tags: python, blackjack

```py
import random

cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]

human_cards = []
ia_cards = []

def deal_card(x):
    int(random.choice(cards))
    return x

deal_card(human_cards)
print(human_cards)
```

When I print it out it gives me the below output:

```
[]
```

I want to have this function working so it gives me 2 random cards for both users.

Comment: It's interesting that `deal_card` essentially does nothing, and then you never call it anyway.

Comment: Ask yourself: where am I appending a value to `human_cards`? where am I dealing **two** cards? Why am I *returning* `x` when I never do anything with the returned value when I call the function? What happens with the value returned by the `int(random.choice(cards))` expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that if you're simulating dealing from a deck of cards, your deal is never just a random pick from 52 cards over and over again. It's a random deal from whatever's *left* in a deck of cards.

Let's create a `Deck` class with a shuffled list of 52 cards, and a `deal_card` function which deals a card and then *removes it from the deck*.

```
import random

class Deck(object):
  def __init__(self):
    suits = ('Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Spades', 'Clubs')
    faces = ('2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace')
    self.deck = [(suit, face) for suit in suits for face in faces]
    random.shuffle(self.deck)
  def deal_card(self):
    try:
      return self.deck.pop()
    except IndexError: 
      return None
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, someone helped me out with this, so I post the answer in case someone needs it also.

```py
import random
cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]

human_cards = []
ia_cards = []

def deal_card(x):
    return random.choice(cards)

human_cards = deal_card(cards)
print(human_cards)
```